# Automatically navigate through Internet using a VPN or not depending upon if the URL is in a black list or not

Tags: proxy, vpn, openvpn, autoproxy

I'm using the [Firefox extension autoproxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/autoproxy/). When we introduce an url, it checks if it is in a black list. If it is in the list, it uses the proxy. If not, it navigates without any proxy.

I made my home computer a proxy server. I reach it through a VPN created by [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). I followed [this tutorial](http://www.eonlinegratis.com/2013/how-to-route-internet-connection-through-teamviewers-vpn/#sthash.2mBAH7fT.dpbs), but I installed [FreeProxy](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/) instead (actually easier to install). I set as the hostname of the proxy: PC2009, and as port: 8080 (I opened the port in my router too).

Hostname of the computer with FreeProxy installed:

[image: hostname of the computer with FreeProxy installed]

The above solution works, but I have to turn on my home pc always I want to navigate through internet. **So I installed [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) and added [these free VPN Servers](http://www.vpnbook.com/) (I followed [this tutorial](http://uwnthesis.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/vpnbook-free-vpn-how-to-set-up-a-vpn-on-windows-7-using-openvpn-to-bypass-firewalls/)). Now, it always navigates through the VPN if it is active.**

**How could I use the VPN** (TAP-Windows Adapter v9) or not (Wireless Adapter) **depending upon the URL is in the black list or not?**

I tried to set as the proxy ip the ip of my router or the DNS, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little of luck I found the solution I wanted:

1) [Download Freegate (portable!)](http://dongtaiwang.com/loc/download.en.php). Actually, I'm not sure if it is a VPN. Read the FAQ for more information.

2) (Optional) You can use Internet Explorer or download the suggested Firefox extension. But I prefer the [Firefox extension autoproxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/autoproxy/). The following image shows how I configured it:

[image: ip: 127.0.0.1; port: 8580]